# Do Zwift bicycle stars represent values or tiers of values?

Tags: zwift

In Zwift, do the number of stars that bicycles and wheels have represent numerical values, or do they represent tiers/buckets of underlying weight/drag coefficient values that are not seen?  To phrase this otherwise, does a 4 star weight correspond to the integer "4", or does it correspond to tier 4, which represents bikes somewhere in the range of 16-18 lbs, for instance?  Aka., are all bikes with the same star rating the exact same in Zwift with regards to performance, or are they all slightly different in ways that Zwift does not portray in its interface?  If the latter, does anyone know of a chart somewhere that maps weights and drag coefficients to the number of stars for bikes and wheels?

Answer (score 6):

The stars *do* correlate with performance, but they are *not* an exact measure of quality. As Andy mentioned, Zwift Insider directly tested the frames in the game. I know he's said the star rankings are poor, which may point to some frames and wheels being misclassified entirely.

My recollection of his test protocol is that he uses an ANT+ simulator to simulate a 75kg rider at a constant 300W, running tests on the flat Tempus Fugit course and the Alpe du Zwift climb (around 9% average gradient, meant to approximate the real life Alpe d'Huez in France). I believe he does this offline, so that no other riders are in the simulation.

The bikes all have simulated weights, and simulated CdAs. Do note that your avatar (and everyone else's) gets their own simulated CdA depending on your height, and the game uses the weight you set. ZwiftInsider reports each bike's performance on the test courses. However, he doesn't report exact weight and CdA, although those values do influence the time. With enough homework, I believe that you should be able to mathematically determine or estimate the weight and CdA. ZI's tables don't have the star ratings, although you could copy the tables to Excel and add the ratings manually if you thought this would be worth investigating.

I am pretty sure Zwift doesn't simulate wind. I believe that ZI has documented how Zwift models rolling resistance, but I think that all the paved roads have pretty low CRRs; I believe ZI commented that the estimated CRR was on par with high performance tires.

We have no insight into how Zwift selects weights and CRR values. I believe that all the differences between frames and wheels are not large, and that they're very small when comparing the top performers in each category. Your own day-to-day variation in performance is probably likely to swamp the difference between, say, the fastest and second fastest road frameset ([currently](https://zwiftinsider.com/fastest-frames/) there's a 4-way tie for first place on flat courses, but it's 3,077 seconds for first place vs. 3,079 seconds for the three second-place frames).

Comment: Zwifts CRR on paved surfaces must be close to non-existant and certainly not even remotely close to my horrible real world surfaces.  I'm at least 5km/h faster on Zwift for the same effort.  I guess it comes back to their 'fun is fast' marketing slogan in that users are more likely to feel good about themselves and come back for another workout if the speed they see makes them feel like they are going well

Answer (score 5):

The stars don't directly correlate to anything unfortunately.

Zwift Insider do a series of articles testing the performance of the different equipment options in game.
Here is the article that gives the ratings/performance of frames:
https://zwiftinsider.com/charts-frames/

Other pages are available including wheels and advice for what is best to buy at what level.